# How to pass dynamic object in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**I am trying to generate multiple chart on single page with ng-repeat. The directive to achieve this accept chart data object as below.**

```js
module.directive('miChart', function () {        
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div></div>',
            scope: {
                chartData: "=value",
                chartObj: "=?"
            },
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('chartData', function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo = $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo || $element[0];
                    $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

**The basic html is as below.**

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
      <mi-chart value="pieChartData" chart-obj="pieChartObj"></mi-chart>
  </td>
  <td>
      <mi-chart ng-repeat="property in Property.Competitors" value="property.PropertyId" chart-obj="property.PropertyId"></mi-chart>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript code to assign values to scope.

```js
dataPromise.then(function (serverResponse) {
    
    var pieChart = serverResponse.data;
    
    var pieChartData = getBaseChartData(pieChart.Primary);

    var chartData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, pieChartData);
    chartData = jQuery.extend(true, chartData, chartDiff);

    $scope.pieChartData = chartData;

    if (pieChart.Competitors.length > 0)
    {
     jQuery.each(pieChart.Competitors, function (index, CompData) {
       
       var pieChartDataComp = getBaseChartData(CompData);

       var chartDataComp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, pieChartDataComp);
       chartDataComp = jQuery.extend(true, chartDataComp, chartDiff);

       $scope[CompData.PropertyId] = chartDataComp;
      }
     });
    }

   });
```

In above code i am able to render my pieChartData with my directive.

But the code doesnt work in case of ng-repeat where i have to create dynamic object based on values in "Property.Competitors".

I can not use string(@) or one way binding(&) in my case as i have to deal with chart(highchart) object and watch functionality.

I am assigning dynamic scope values in my service with server side calls.

Can anybody help me out to generate multiple chart with ng-repeat and directive.

How can i create dynamic object and keep watch on that?

Comment: did you try repeating a `<div>` and put `<mi-chart>` inside repeating div? WHat is structure of `Property.Competitors` ? Seems strange that chartData would be in a property named `PropertyId`

Comment: I have already tried it using <div mi-chart ng-repeat="comp in Competitors.Ids" value="comp" chart-obj="comp"></div> but that also doesnt work. Property.Competitors is an array of property with attribute PropertyId.

Comment: how can an ID be enough data for a chart? Try putting `my-chart` inside the div, not at repeat level

Comment: I am assigning chart object to $scope[id]. I wanted to use that same scope object and that is the only reason i am using id as a scope name. So my final code would be <div mi-chart value="3" chart-obj="3"></div> and in controller i am assigning $scope[3] = ChartObject.

Comment: well not enough is known about `doesn't work` without more debugging info from console. Also not known if `$scope[3]` is defined since you are working with isolated scope directive. Your directive shows the data passed in  as chartData not as ID ... you probably have a scope problem